# Hamachi and FTP/HTTP

Tags: http, ftp, tunnel, hamachi

I'm trying to connect to an FTP server over HTTP. Is there any way I can use a VPN like Hamachi and tunnel through my home PC, then connect tothe FTP via HTTP or another port?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with FTP over HTTP is not port mapping, but being able to translate HTTP commands to FTP. Something like [mod_proxy_ftp](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy_ftp.html) should help. Note that FTP over HTTP proxies tend to support only fetching of files and listing of directories, i.e. they convert a directory URL to a LIST commands, and a file URL to a RETR command.

I realize I might not have answered your exact question, so apologies if there is a strong reason why you need to use VPN and not a proxy. Still I can't see how a VPN would do the protocol conversion.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to tunnel somehow.